# Insert html into beginning of angular repeater

Tags: angularjs

If I have a ul:

```
<ul>
    <li>Specific line</li>

    <!-- Commence repeater here -->

    <li><% item.Name %></li>

    <!-- ---------------------- -->
</ul>
```

How would I go about producing the above... The idea being there is a static `<li>` before the repeater runs.

I've currently got this, but you can see the issue...

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-repeat="n in ProductCount">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a></li>

    <li class="active"><a ng-click="Paginate( n )"  href="#"><% n %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The first line needs to be there once, then then repeater can kick in for the pagination parts

Comment: Do you mean ngRepeat? What angular version are you using?

Comment: Just put the `ng-repeat` directive on the `li` between those comments?

Comment: Put that as the answer. Works like a charm. Thanks brosky!